# How to format date in ExactTarget query?

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to format date using the Exact Target Query builder tool?

Is there Sql type convert function that can be used to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to the Query Activities within the ET application.  They sit on top of a SQL Server backend, with 90% of the SQL Server functionality exposed to the end user.  So yes, things like CONVERT still work.

The only way the formatting actually matters is if you are storing the results in a field of type string.  Otherwise, it will get stored as a SQL dateTime, and you will need to format accordingly when you pull the value out.

Hope this helps!